# input delay in Ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

The following simple program for practice changes text color every time the uses presses enter,using just a simple random number attached to color pairs in a Switch Statement.

However somehow there is a delay and I cannot press enter faster than every 1 or 2 seconds. In theory changing colors should be as fast as I press the enter button. Any tips on how to resolve this? I tried using nodelay and cbreak options but these do not have any effect. Also tried to limit the amount of refreshes etc.

Thanks for checking

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <time.h>

char input();
int generaterandomnumber();

int main()

{

    
char hitenter;
int randomnumber;
char string[60]={"This text changes colors all the time when you press enter"};

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    nodelay(stdscr,true);
    start_color();
    
init_pair(1, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_RED);
init_pair(2, COLOR_RED, COLOR_GREEN); 
init_pair(3, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_YELLOW); 
init_pair(4, COLOR_YELLOW, COLOR_BLUE);
init_pair(5, COLOR_BLUE, COLOR_MAGENTA);
init_pair(6, COLOR_MAGENTA, COLOR_CYAN);
init_pair(7, COLOR_CYAN, COLOR_WHITE);
init_pair(8, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(9, COLOR_BLACK, COLOR_GREEN);
init_pair(10, COLOR_GREEN, COLOR_BLUE);
    
    WINDOW *thebox=newwin(5,60,10,10);
    box(thebox,0,0);
    
    
    mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
    
    refresh();
    wrefresh(thebox);
    
    while(1)
    {
        hitenter=input();
        randomnumber=generaterandomnumber();
        
        switch (randomnumber)
        
        {
        
            case 1:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(1));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(1));
            break;
            case 2:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(2));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(2));
            break;
            case 3:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(3));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(3));
            break;
            case 4:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(4));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(4));
            break;
            case 5:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(5));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(5));
            break;
            case 6:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(6));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(6));
            break;
            case 7:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(7));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(7));
            break;
            case 8:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(8));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(8));
            break;
            case 9:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(9));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(9));
            break;
            case 10:
            wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(10));
            mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
            wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(10));
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        wrefresh(thebox);
        refresh();
    }
        

        endwin();

        return 0;
}


char input()
{
    char temp;
    do
    {
        temp=getch();
    }
        while (temp!='\n');
        return temp;
}

int generaterandomnumber()
{
    int temp;
    srand(time(NULL));
    temp=(rand()%(9+1));
    return temp;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int generaterandomnumber()
{
    int temp;
    srand(time(NULL));
    temp=(rand()%(9+1));
    return temp;    
}
```

This. Not only this function is unnecessary since all it does is `return (rand()%(9+1))`, the call to `srand` is apparently what takes time. I didn't know `srand` was so time consuming, but directly calling `rand` from the `main` appears to solve the problem.

Regardless, `srand` is a function that you call once in your program prior to calling `rand`, there is no need to call it again each time you call `rand` in your program.

Just call `srand` in your `main` before the main loop. If you want to keep the `generaterandomnumber` function, you can, after removing the `srand` from it. Alternatively, simply call `rand` in place of it.

---

Irrelevant of the question, why not simply:

```
wattron(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(randomnumber));
mvwprintw(thebox,1,1,"%s", string);
wattroff(thebox,COLOR_PAIR(randomnumber));
```

instead of that massive `switch-case` statement?